# passing a query string parameter through auth0 to the app

Tags: asp.net, authentication, owin, auth0

I have an ASP.NET + OWIN app.  I have auth0 setup using the nuget package they provide.  Log In/Out works as expected.

I'm trying to create a kind of invite system.  When a record is created in the app's database, I want to send email with a register link containing an invite code that references back to the record.  When the user clicks the link, I'd like to get the invite code and create a link in the app's database back to the user.  I've tried to set this up by creating a rule that "enriches" the user's profile with invite code.  Most of the time, the code isn't part of the returned user identity though.  Every once in awhile it will work, but not often.  I can't explain why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Any insight would be a big help.

Comment: I can't exactly understand the full picture of what you're trying to achieve. Can you try to clarify your goals and maybe even include the code for the rule you already have?

Comment: Basically, if the return URL contained a query string, it would drop get dropped some point in the process.  I finally gave up and changed the URL to move the parameter into the path instead of the query.